# Issue about WebBrowser component

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, webbrowser-control

Why WebBrowser component does not allow other components (button, textbox, etc) is created over it? I was using Popup to contain the components that need to use, but to move the program screen popups do not follow the screen remain static in the place they were created.

```
<Grid>

    <WebBrowser x:Name="wbBrowser" />

    <Canvas ClipToBounds="False">
        <Popup PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=wbBrowser}" IsOpen="true" AllowsTransparency="True" >
            <Button>asdasdasdsadasd</Button>
        </Popup>
    </Canvas>

</Grid>
```

Comment: Give us some code to work with :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WebBrowser control in WPF is actually a wrapped version of the WebBrowser control from WinForms. As such it is always rendered above other WPF controls. The only things that you can show above would be another window.

The WebBrowser control is pretty limited in WPF, I believe it uses IE8, so there is no HTML5 support. There are some open source browser controls for WPF that are newer that likely don't suffer from the same limitations of the built in WPF control. Take a look at this project: https://wpfchromium4.codeplex.com/

Comment: I will create a vehicle tracking software in WPF, is possible with Chromium?

Comment: I don't see why not. But if you are only using a browser so you can get a map in your app, why not use the Bing Maps WPF control. This will give you a lot more power as you will be working with pure WPF/.NET and not messing around with mixing JavaScript in a browser control. You can find documentation for the Bing Maps WPF control here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh750210.aspx Feel free to reach out to me if you have any questions about the Bing Maps WPF control. I know it pretty well.

Comment: Thanks for the replies and willingness to help me. God bless you :)